# How to evaluate the validity of my teaching methods through analyzing the data of the students' ranks in a grade through time?

Tags: references, ranking

> I also posted the question at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4793565/how-to-evaluate-the-validity-of-my-teaching-methods-through-analyzing-the-data-o

### Problems I want to solve

I want to be a high school teacher, and I have some self-considered great ideas of teaching methods. Before that, I want to be a tutor first, and perform these methods to some students who have not performed my methods a period of time, which will give me their ranking data in the grade of their exams before and after my methods are performed. Here comes **the problem 1**: How to analyze this ranking data to evaluate the validity of my methods?

When I am a high school teacher, I will perform my methods to all of the students in my class. Then I will get the ranking data in the grade of the exams for the students whether performed my methods or not. Here comes **the problem 2**: How to analyze this ranking data to evaluate the validity of my methods?

**Note** that there will be many exams, and I have to take the trends of the students' ranking in the grade into consideration. For example, if a student's ranking becomes higher and higher through time, this to some degree will prove the validity of my methods.

### Or to express it in a more mathematical way

**Problem 1**: There is a variable $y$ fluctuating through times $t_1...t_m$，where $t$s are discrete. During these times $t_1...t_m$，there is a factor variable $x$ which $x=x_1$. Then at time $t_{m+1}$, the factor variable $x$ changes to $x=x_2$, and $x$ maintain its value through times $t_{m+1}...t_n$, and $y$ continues to fluctuate through these times. The question is: How to evaluate the effect of $x$ to $y$?

**Problem 2**: There are $b$ variables $y_1...y_b$ fluctuating through times $t_1...t_n$, where $t$s are discrete. For $1\leq i\leq a$, the factor variable for $y_i$ is $x_i=x_1$, and for $a+1\leq i\leq b$, the factor variable for $y_i$ is $x_i=x_2$. The question is: How to evaluate the effect of $x$ to $y$?

**Note**: The trend of $y$ through $t$ should be taken into consideration.

---

Can you give me some articles to do a research?

Comment: It sounds like your data are not up to the task.  You need some kind of control group that was subjected to a comparable intervention that did not involve your methods.  Without that, no matter how dramatic an improvement you might find, you will still have no basis to attribute that result to your specific methods.  Indeed, a sceptic might suggest that somebody else using different methods would have obtained greater improvements, but you don't seem to have any data to prove them incorrect.

Comment: @whuber Forgive me for asking this, for I'm not professional, but why aren't **before and after** my methods are performed and students **whether** performed my methods **or not** making a comparable intervention? Why aren't the different values of $x$ which $x=x_1{\rm or}x_2$ making a comparable intervention?

Comment: Because anything that occurred between the before and after can be credited with causing any observed change.  That's why you need an adequate control group.